# Python lxml. Use findall with a variable

Tags: python, lxml

An XML snippet looks like this:

```
    <certificate name='first_item'>First text,</certificate>
    <certificate name='second_item'>Second text,</certificate>
    <certificate name='second_item'>Third text,</certificate
```

I can easily pick out an element using findall():

```
mystring = xmlroot.findall('certificate[@name="first_name"]').text
```

But I can't do that using a variable:

```
item_option = 'first_item'
mystring = xmlroot.findall('certificate[@name=item_option]').text
full_search_string = 'certificate[@name="first_name"]'
mystring = xmlroot.findall(full_search_string).text
```

Both of these last options fail. How do I insert a String variable into the findall() method?
If I don't want to hard code the filter based on name attribute, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try concatenating the variable to the string. Your variable is being passed as a string and therefore not interpreted.

```
mystring = xmlroot.findall('certificate[@name="' + item_option + '"]')
```

Comment: That did it! I knew it was something simple I was missing. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Happy to hear it!

Comment: What? The code in this answer does not work. `findall()` returns a list. You cannot apply `.text` on a list. Also note that attribute value in the predicate must be in quotes (`item_option = '"first_item"'`).

Comment: @Bagheera asked how to pass a variable to findall. I didn't verify that the rest of his code was functional. I added the quotes to the predicate and removed the .text function. Thanks for pointing that out.